# Variable for adjusting the increase of a numbers value on a curve

Tags: math, increment, curve

I want to increase the value of a number on a curve. I have:

```
for($i=1; $i<=40; $i++){

    $number = cosh($i);
    echo $number;

}
```

This example curves up too fast. How to do I add a variable to this code that will allow me to adjust the rate the number increases? I looking to adjust the slope of the curve. I'm not looking to adjust the value of the beginning number (ie $i = $i*.3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Countless ways to do this. Here are two:

- Change the *exponent* of `$i`. Since your starting value is 1, and 1 raised to any power is still 1. Choose a power in the range `(0, 1)` (non-inclusive), e.g.:

  ```
  $number = cosh(pow($i, 0.25));
  ```
- Slightly more general - a power or a multiple of the difference between `$i` and starting value:

  ```
  $start = 1;
  $end = 40;

  $const = 0.01;
  for ($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i++) {
      $number = cosh($start + ($i - $start) * $const);
      // ...

  // or...

  $power = 0.25;
  for ($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i++) {
      $number = cosh($start + pow($i - $start, $power));
      // ...

  // or a combination of both.
  ```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to change $i in the for definition, change it within the function call:

```
for($i=1; $i<=40; $i++){

    $number = cosh($i*.3);
    echo $number;

}
```

Comment: This is not what I looking for. I doesn't change rate of the curve increase. It only changes the initial value.